# Configure TypeScript on Azure with Continuous Build

Tags: azure, angular, typescript, azure-devops

We have a large web application which used TypeScript and Angular2 which is working fine locally.
Because we have issues on getting it deployed on Azure we've created a simple Angular2 application using a template. This application is just showing the famous `Hello World`.

We use Visual Studio Team Services as our GIT Repo. We also use Continuous Build so when we commit, Azure compiles and builds our application.

We are now in the process of letting Azure transpile our TypeScript files into JavaScript.

We've tried a lot of options but are now stuck with these errors:

```
[..]/AppData/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(17,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
[..]/AppData/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(237,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'EPSILON'.
[..]/AppData/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(272,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'.
[..]/AppData/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(279,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER'.
[..]/AppData/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(565,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
[..]/AppData/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(566,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
[..]/AppData/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(795,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'flags'.
[..]/AppData/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(823,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
[..]/AppData/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(833,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
[..]/AppData/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(849,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
[..]/AppData/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(861,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
[..]/AppData/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(871,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
[..]/AppData/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(886,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
[..]/AppData/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(1282,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts(3,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts(6,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts(7,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts(245,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'EPSILON'.
typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts(280,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'.
typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts(287,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER'.
typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts(343,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'flags'.
typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts(495,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts(558,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts(567,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts(578,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts(588,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts(603,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts(617,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
```

These errors appear in the build log and when I run `tsc` in de wwwroot using the Kudo console.

At least this means Azure is attempting to transpile our files. But some where we've got the configuration wrong.

The content of `wwwroot/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "public/",
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/modules",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

What do we need to change to get pass these errors?

A side question is: Azure says the build and deploy is successful but the log shows errors and only partially is deployed. How to tell Azure not to continue when transpiling goes wrong?

Comment: Do you have `reference` Directives in your TypeScript files? There are a few cases where they can cause this behavior by loading the same declaration file twice.

Comment: I was away for a few days. I did some more research and changed the target from "es6" to "es5". Now the ts-files are transpiled and I can see the js-files on the server. But when I go to the /src/ folder that contains the index.html I get `{{#unless environment.production}} {{/unless}} Loading... {{#each scripts.polyfills}} {{/each}}` in the browser. Meaning the Angular2 tags are not parsed. Anybody more ideas or suggestions?